# Combine two numpy matrixes

Tags: numpy, matrix, append

I have two numpy matrixes:

```
name    dimensions
title   (284,855)
para    (284, 4930)
```

The title array contains the title of a page and the para contains the content where the first element of the title array is the title for the first element of the para array. I wish to append them, to create a new matrix, `X`, with the dimensions `(284, 5785)`. How can I do this using Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `concatenate`:

```
import numpy as np
new_matrix = np.concatenate((title, para), axis=1)
```